# How to move buttons next to the list item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

How can I move the two buttons next to the displayed task? My styling code below:
`.task-container` is a div, `.task-list` is ul, `.task-item` is li and 2 buttons.

```js
// Selectors

const taskInput = document.querySelector(".input-task");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
const taskList = document.querySelector(".task-list");

// Event Listeners

addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);

// Functions
function addTask(event) {
  // Prevent form from submiting
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("hello");
  //   Task Div
  const taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
  taskDiv.classList.add("task");

  //   Create Li
  const newTask = document.createElement("li");
  newTask.innerText = taskInput.value;
  newTask.classList.add("task-item");

  taskDiv.appendChild(newTask);

  //   Completed button
  const completedBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completedBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
  completedBtn.classList.add("completed-btn");
  taskDiv.appendChild(completedBtn);

  // Creating Delete Button
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
  deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-btn");
  taskDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  //   Appent to list
  taskList.appendChild(taskDiv);

  //   Clear task input value
  taskInput.value = "";
}
```

```css
.task-list {
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 30%;
}

.tasks-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.task-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
}

.completed-btn {
  color: #ff9551;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border: none;
}

.delete-btn {
  color: #ff1e00;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Task List</h1>
    <form id="new-task">
      <input type="text" class="input-task" placeholder="Add Task" />
      <button class="btn-add" id="button-add" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h3>Tasks</h3>
      <div id="tasks-container">
        <ul class="task-list">
          <!-- <div class="task"></div> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried to add `display: flex;`, `block`, or `inline-block` to the buttons but it doesn't work. Also tried to style the container and body but the buttons stay below the `.task-item`.

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: sure, I added. I create div .task, li and buttons through javaScript

Comment: Can you add that js? It's important we have an [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `.task`.

```js
// Selectors

const taskInput = document.querySelector(".input-task");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".btn-add");
const taskList = document.querySelector(".task-list");

// Event Listeners

addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);

// Functions
function addTask(event) {
  // Prevent form from submiting
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("hello");
  //   Task Div
  const taskDiv = document.createElement("div");
  taskDiv.classList.add("task");

  //   Create Li
  const newTask = document.createElement("li");
  newTask.innerText = taskInput.value;
  newTask.classList.add("task-item");

  taskDiv.appendChild(newTask);

  //   Completed button
  const completedBtn = document.createElement("button");
  completedBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
  completedBtn.classList.add("completed-btn");
  taskDiv.appendChild(completedBtn);

  // Creating Delete Button
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
  deleteBtn.classList.add("delete-btn");
  taskDiv.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  //   Appent to list
  taskList.appendChild(taskDiv);

  //   Clear task input value
  taskInput.value = "";
}
```

```css
.task-list {
  list-style: none;
  min-width: 30%;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

.tasks-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.task-item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px grey;
}

.completed-btn {
  color: #ff9551;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border: none;
}

.delete-btn {
  color: #ff1e00;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.task {
  max-width: min-content;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Task List</h1>
    <form id="new-task">
      <input type="text" class="input-task" placeholder="Add Task" />
      <button class="btn-add" id="button-add" type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section>
      <h3>Tasks</h3>
      <div id="tasks-container">
        <ul class="task-list">
          <!-- <div class="task"></div> -->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @zulfiya Also, I addded `padding-inline-start: 0;` to your `ul`.